# Rohloff gear can only shift between 3 and 4, even when gear disconnected from hub

Tags: rohloff

My Rohloff gearhub will only shift between gears 3 and 4 (I think; display long ceased to be readable, but it's two low gears).  I tried adjusting the shifter cable tension but it makes no difference.  When I disconnect the gearbox from the hub it still doesn't shift.

[image: gearbox]

The [owner's manual](https://www.rohloff.de/en/service/downloads/documentation/index.html) troubleshooting section has an item "twist shifter does not turn freely", but beyond 3 and 4, my twist shifter does not turn at all, not even under considerable force.  When I do shift (heavily) between 3 and 4, I do see a slight movement in the cables.  I am not able to manually pull the cables out of the gearbox.

Until yesterday, shifting worked through all gears albeit somewhat heavily.  I took the bicycle on a train, where I strapped it.  After I got off the train, the problem appeared.

What might cause this?

Comment: I would say something's jammed.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Possibly.  It was dirty but cleaning didn't solve it.  I'm hesitant to open it for fear of breaking things.

Comment: Rohloff famously has a great warranty. Take it to a dealer.

Comment: @RoboKaren Apparently, [warranty is two years](https://www.rohloff.de/en/service/faqs/).  My Speedhub is almost 8 years old (bought in spring 2009).  Warranty also requires a yearly *service check (...) by a professional bike workshop*, which I didn't have since between 2009 and 2014 I lived 1600 km from the nearest Rohloff-capable bike shop, so I had to maintain my bike myself.  Shifter cables are even listed as a wearable part and I'm still using the original ones, despite a traffic accident in November 2013.  I can't see anything wrong but it would be unsurprising if they need replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check the cables.**

Rohloff classifies the gear shifter cables as a consumable.  They may wear out and need replacement over the years.  Check the gear shifter cables carefully for any damage; they might need replacement.  Be aware that they are not ordinary cables, but that you need special Rohloff gear cables to fit.

In my case, there was a damage in the gear shifter cables.  Replacement resolved the problem.